# Programmatically capture the location & content of all embedded text items within a .PDF file?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a series of .pdf documents that contain lots of separate instances of embedded text, and I need to be able to loop through each instance and programmatically capture two things: (1) the size and location of the rectangle that outlines each instance of text AND (2) the actual text itself within each of those rectangles.

The goal here is to be able to use JS to automatically insert a button over the top of each text item. I need to be able to give each button a shape/size and location that corresponds (at least roughly) with the existing text rectangle, and I need to name each button the exact text string that is contained within each rectangle.

Can such a thing be done with JS? It seems like it ought to be possible but I definitely don't know enough JS to actually do it.

The .pdf files I am working with are all building floor plans, and each instance of embedded text is a room number for a specific room within each floor, as below:

[image]

I have working JS code to create an arbitrary loop of buttons (assuming I had an array of rectangle definitions and text/names available to size, position, and name each one), but I don't know how to programmatically refer to each embedded text item -- neither the size/location of the text rectangle, nor the content of the text itself.

There doesn't seem to be a handy function that will loop through all instances of *embedded text* within the document, and capture the relevant information, as I could with another object (say, hyperlinks by using the getLinks command).

This is the final step in implementing a larger project, and creating each of these buttons by hand will be impractical since there are multiple thousands of them required by the full set of floor plans.

Comment: Are you trying to insert buttons into the PDF file?  Are you displaying the PDF by embedding it in the browser window and if so does this not require a plugin or are you rendering the PDF in the browser window first?

Comment: @thril What I had in mind was to insert buttons into the pdf file, so what I had pictured was a solution that would/could function entirely within Acrobat, for instance. Although in the final implementation of the whole project, the .pdf file will generally be opened from within a webbrowser control of an Excel userform. So if there are any solutions that require the interaction of a browser, it sounds like that would be a possibility as well. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Since you are using Excel, you can likely integrate nicely with VBA or worst case create a library in .net and use that from VBA. The web side would only need to facilitate communication. Have you explored options besides a web view?

Comment: @thril I actually fancy myself to be almost semi-proficient in VBA, but so far I've had basically no luck getting VBA to recognize or operate on JS-based controls in the .pdf file. I'm sure I'm just ignorant of the broad-stroke commands that I'd need to get started, but I haven't had any success with having JS and VBA play very nicely together in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually been able to accomplish what I needed to do using the getPageNthWord and getPageNthWordQuads commands from the native Acrobat Javascript, and did not need to resort to PDF.js or any other languages or libraries. In my case, it was also necessary to employ the Matrix2D function to translate between the "quad" (for capturing location and dimension of each word) and "rect" (for defining space and location of new buttons) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, all you can display is HTML content.

PDFJS (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) is a javascript library that can be used as a javascript "viewer" for PDF, and also understand the very essence of PDF. Feel free to use it and extend it to your needs (making area interactive or so..)

You can also try to render pdf to images on the server side (e.g. using xpdf pdftopng), then use a pdf "tokenizer" (e.g http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html ) and display interactive area on top of the original picture

Comment: PDF.js has getTextContent call that will let you to extract all text items (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L1058). See also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/text-only/pdf2svg.js example

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. At the moment, it looks promising that I'll be able to use getTextContent to implement what I need to do in this case. Will report back if/when I'm successful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to do what you want it would have to be done server side Linux/Windows or desktop app. The easiest would be to render your pages to images and do any interactive overlay with HTML on top of those images.  What it sounds like you want to do can only be accomplished using more powerful languages than web JS / HTML libraries would offer.

There are Java and .NET libraries that are powerful to work with PDF's and accomplish this.  A good open-source one is http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

There are more powerful ones which are not free such as: https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/net-sdk/

You could write a service that takes an input PDF and outputs images per page as well as the image path, co-ordinates and titles per page into a JSON file. Then in HTML/JS load the JSON into an array of objects and loop to insert the images and apply an `image-map` to them with mouse-over or `<a>` link as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can search text programatically in PDF with HiQPdf library. You can find more details and code samples in the [Search Text In PDF blog page](https://hiqpdf-html-to-pdf.com/2016/07/11/search-text-in-pdf-using-hiqpdf-library/). The code sample for this is:

```
// get the PDF file
string pdfFile = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\DemoFiles\Pdf\InputPdf.pdf";

// get the text to search
string textToSearch = textBoxTextToSearch.Text;

// create the PDF text extractor
PdfTextExtract pdfTextExtract = new PdfTextExtract();

int fromPdfPageNumber = int.Parse(textBoxFromPage.Text);
int toPdfPageNumber = textBoxToPage.Text.Length > 0 ? int.Parse(textBoxToPage.Text) : 0;

// search the text in PDF document
PdfTextSearchItem[] searchTextInstances = pdfTextExtract.SearchText(pdfFile, textToSearch,
            fromPdfPageNumber, toPdfPageNumber, checkBoxMatchCase.Checked, checkBoxMatchWholeWord.Checked);

// load the PDF file to highlight the searched text
PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfDocument.FromFile(pdfFile);

// highlight the searched text in PDF document
foreach (PdfTextSearchItem searchTextInstance in searchTextInstances)
{
    PdfRectangle pdfRectangle = new PdfRectangle(searchTextInstance.BoundingRectangle);

    // set rectangle color and opacity
    pdfRectangle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    pdfRectangle.Opacity = 30;

    // highlight the text
    pdfDocument.Pages[searchTextInstance.PdfPageNumber - 1].Layout(pdfRectangle);
}

// write the modified PDF document
try
{
    // write the PDF document to a memory buffer
    byte[] pdfBuffer = pdfDocument.WriteToMemory();

    // inform the browser about the binary data format
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    // let the browser know how to open the PDF document and the file name
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=SearchText.pdf; size={0}",
                pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

    // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

    // call End() method of HTTP response to stop ASP.NET page processing
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
finally
{
    pdfDocument.Close();
}
```